# Socket always receive 0 length data after DuplicateAndClose

Tags: c#, sockets, appdomain, system.net

The purpose to duplicate the socket by calling the DuplicateAndClose method is to accept the socket in main AppDomain but to process it in a separated AppDomain so the process logic can be unloaded & updated without restarting the process.

Currently all the logic happened in the same AppDomain and the major problem is that after I invoke method DuplicateAndClose and create a new socket based on the SocketInformation, that socket always receive 0 length data.

Does any one know what is the correct step to use the DuplicateAndClose method and receive data from the duplicated socket?  Thanks.

**Listening on port and accept socket**

```
Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    using (var listenSocket = new Socket(afamily, stype, ptype))
    {
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
            listenSocket.Bind(iep);
            listenSocket.Listen(5000);

            Console.WriteLine($"Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} listening on port {port}");

            while (!isending)
            {
                Socket ask = null;
                try
                {
                    var handler = new DomainSocketHandler(GetType().FullName);
                    ask = listenSocket.Accept();
                    handler.Handle(ask);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}));
th.Start();
```

**Duplicate socket and receive data**

```
var si = accepted.DuplicateAndClose(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
var info = si;
using (var psk = new Socket(info))
{
    int len = 0;
    var buf = new byte[4096];
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            len = psk.Receive(buf);
            if (len < 1 && psk.Available < 1)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    string response = @"Connection:close
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8

<html><body>Success</body></html>";
    UTF8Encoding en = new UTF8Encoding();
    var bytes = en.GetBytes(response);
    psk.Send(bytes);
}
```

Comment: Why is placing the listener in the remote appdomain not an option?

Comment: It sounds like the other side has already closed their end of the socket. What does the client code look like?

Comment: If you put listener at a remote domain, when you want to update the dll, you have to shutdown the listener within the AppDomain which will cause the port stop working for a while.  This will impact the availability of the server.